# jsonresult me redirecciona a pagina con solo json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una duda, tengo este método en una vista en asp.net MVC 5:

```
    $('#enviar-data').click(function () {

        //var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

        var form = $('#formx');

       // console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: form.prop('action'),
            data: { montoAdicionalOInicial: montoaddic },//form.serialize(),
            //headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Message);               
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            error: function () { alert("Ocurrio un error inesperado. Reinicie la operacion."); },
            cache: false
        });
    });
```

Este es mi método del controlador :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AbrirCajachica(decimal? montoAdicionalOInicial)
{
    MessageModel message = new MessageModel();
    CajaChicaDA objCajaDA = new CajaChicaDA();
    bool existeCajaChicaAbierta = objCajaDA.VerificarCajaChicaAbiertas();
    CajaChica cajadeldiaexiste = objCajaDA.ObtenerCajaChicaDelDia();

    if (!existeCajaChicaAbierta && cajadeldiaexiste == null)
    {
        CajaChica objCajaAnterior = objCajaDA.ObtenerCajaChicaDiaAnterior();

        CajaChica objnuevocaja = new CajaChica();
        objnuevocaja.Fecha = DateTime.Now.Date;
        objnuevocaja.Estado = "A";

        if (objCajaAnterior != null)
        {

            if (montoAdicionalOInicial.HasValue)
            {
                objnuevocaja.MontoInicial = objCajaAnterior.MontoFinal.Value + montoAdicionalOInicial.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                objnuevocaja.MontoInicial = objCajaAnterior.MontoFinal.Value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objnuevocaja.MontoInicial = montoAdicionalOInicial.Value;
        }
        int IdCajaChica = objCajaDA.NuevaCajaChica(objnuevocaja);
        int resultstock = 0;
        if (IdCajaChica > 0)
        {
            StockDiarioDA objStockDiarioDA = new StockDiarioDA();
            resultstock = objStockDiarioDA.LLenarStockDiario(IdCajaChica);
        }
        if (resultstock > 0)
        {
            message.Message = "Se creo la caja chica del dia de hoy correctamente;";
            message.Tipo = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            message.Message = "Ocurrio un error.";
            message.Tipo = 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        message.Message = "No se puede crear caja chica.";
        message.Tipo = 2;
    }
    return Json(message);
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien llega la data y la proceso, pero cuando llega al `success` me redirecciona a una web vacío con los datos del json de respuesta:

`{"Message":"No se puede crear caja chica.","Tipo":2}`

¿Hay algo que tengo que configurar?

Answer (score 0):

Modifica tu Javascript:

```
$('#enviar-data').click(function (e) { //Añade la "e" 
    e.preventDefault();
   …
});
```

Lo que sucede es que el comportamiento del botón es ir a donde diga el `action` del `form`, necesitas decirle que no lo haga mediante [preventDefault](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp).

Comment: eso no me pasa cuando lo hago con modales, me parece muy raro

Comment: Esto sucede cuando hay un botón (sea `button` o `input`) DENTRO de un `form`, con los modales, como generalmente no hay un form, no se ejecuta ningún `action` y responde sin problemas al script que quieras. Ahora bien, ¿te sirvió la respuesta o hay que seguir explorando?

Comment: excelente gracias, si me sirvio